# Why would you create a class instance using (CustomClass) "string" in Java?

Tags: java, class, constructor, type-conversion, instance

I'm new to Java and working on a existing, big project. A couple times, I came across code like this: `variable = (CustomClass) "string";`.
Now, I really can't figure out why you would do that and how it is different from `variable = new CustomClass("string");`. The CustomClass has a constructor with one string argument.
In some situations, the above code just won't work which is why I came across it. But first, I want to understand what it does and Google doesn't seem to help. Or it is very possible I just don't know yet how to phrase the question accurately

Comment: The code you came across appears to be trying to cast a string literal to `CustomClass`.  This is suspicious to me, because `String` is a final class, can't be extended, and so I doubt that this class could be used to cast a string.

Comment: You can't cast `String` to `CustomClass` and still have the code compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variable = (CustomClass) another_variable_reference;`

Above line of code will tell JVM that `another_variable_reference` is-a class type of `variable` reference class, here `CustomClass`. So assign the reference to which `another_variable_reference` it is pointing to reference `variable`

`variable = new CustomClass(another_variable_reference);`

Above will create a new Object of `CustomClass` and assign the object reference to the variable

Hence, in the first case, we create a new `reference` which point's to an existing object while in second, we create a new `Object` and assign it's reference to `variable`

Comment: Finally found my problem. `another_variable_reference` was actually `jListCustomers.getSelectedValue()`, which my GUI editor somehow changed to type `JList<String>`. Changing the type to `JList` solved it.